# IE problems with Media Queries

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

OK, this script checks the media type using css media queries. The idea is that I create a div (pre-DOM) and a style element with media queries, and if the style is applied then the media query was true. This works in Firefox 5, but not in IE 9.

```
/** Detect Browser Media **/
if(!window.mediaQuery){
    window.mediaQuery = function(query){
    var boolean = 0;

    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.media = query;
    style.innerHTML = '#mediaQuery{width:5px;}';
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'mediaQuery';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);

    if(div.offsetWidth == 5){boolean = 1;}
    console.log(div.offsetWidth," ",boolean);

    return { match:boolean };
    }
}
```

This returns "5 1" in FF 5 and in Chrome console, but it returns "919 0" in IE 9. What is IE doing here? How can I work around?

Here is an example of the function call:
mediaQuery('screen and (min-width: 480px)').match

After some testing I have found that the width matches 100% of the screen width. 
Why isn't the media query working in IE, it works in FF and Chrome... 
Maybe IE is just not processing the CSS before I test the width in javascript?

Comment: interesting enough, if you add a body tag instead of a div it changes to 903 0

Comment: if I change it to height and check the outerHeight or any variation of property to check height (getClientRects, getBoundingClientRect,offsetHeight) it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.
IE only applies css to elements in the body, in order to get it to use the css you have to place the div within a fake body (because the real body hasn't loaded yet). Here is the finished script:

```
/** Detect Browser Media **/
if(!window.mediaQuery){
    window.mediaQuery = function(query){
    var boolean = 0;

    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type="text/css";
    style.media = query;
    if(style.styleSheet){style.styleSheet.cssText='#mediaQuery{width:30px;}';}else{
        var MyCssText=document.createTextNode("#mediaQuery{width:30px;}");
        style.appendChild(MyCssText);
    }

    document.head.appendChild(style);

    bod = document.createElement('body');
    bod.id="fakeBody";
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'mediaQuery';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(bod);
    bod.appendChild(div);

    if(div.offsetWidth == 30){boolean = 1;}
    console.log(div.offsetWidth," ",boolean);

    return { match:boolean };
    }
}
```